# Integrating a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I have the integral

$ \int_{C(0;2)} \frac{e^z}{z^3+9}dz $

I was told I could use Cauchy's Integral formula but I'm still stuck, I'm not sure how to apply it.

Any help would be great!

Comment: If I interprete the integral right, the way is a circle around the origin with radius $2$. In this case, the roots of the denominator are outside this circle, so the integral has value $0$.

Comment: Exactly, I should have specified in the question, sorry. That intuitively makes sense, is there a specific theorem to refer to here?

Comment: Yes, the residue theorem : A complex integral over a closed way is equal to the sum of the residues corresponding to the poles the curve surrounds, multiplied with $2\pi i$

Comment: Hmm... I haven't come across the residue theorem. Might there be an alternative way using the Cauchy Integral formula?

Comment: To calculate integrals ? If you mean Cauchy's integral formula, perhaps. As far as I know, Cauchy's integral theorem only works in the case we have in the example.

Comment: I meant formula, sorry. I edited just before you commented

Comment: I can only remember that we can calculate special Riemann-integrals by using a complex function and by seperating real and imaginary part. But I do not know the details at the moment.

Comment: It's just Cauchy's theorem.